# How to write png images using Swift cross platform

Tags: swift, image, png, cross-platform, static-libraries

I am writing a little [cross-platform raytracer in Swift](https://github.com/Blackjacx/SwiftTrace). At the moment I am stuck at the point writing out the generated image. I searched for some days now for a library but what I found was only the following:

- writing PNG's using [UIImagePNGRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1624096-uiimagepngrepresentation):  nope thats iOS only
- [lodepng](http://lodev.org/lodepng/) - a lightweight c lib consisting of only 2 files (.c and .h): looks very promising but it won't link with my swift program - very disappointing
- [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html): full blown png library that is way too much for my purpose.

The image output is the last brick to the initial raytracing algorithm written in swift. I would be really thankful if anybody has an idea how to accomplish this. Maybe somebody can give helpful advice how to solve this problem.

The other option would be to find a very simple image format for which either a lib exists or for which I can write a Swift algorithm for myself.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't link with my Swift program"?

Comment: I can call C functions from the lodepng library. No problem for the compiler. But at link time the linker complains that it cannot find the symbol for the C-method call. I also saw that the compiler generated .o files in the derived/intermediates folder. Any ideas?

Comment: There's this open-source library (pure Swift): https://github.com/kelvin13/swift-png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use netpbm which is a trivial format, then use a third-party converter such as ImageMagick  or GraphicsMagick to convert it to final form.

You can use the netpbm library, or simply write the pixels yourself.

The format is described [here](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html)

A typical PPM file looks like this, where the "P3" magic number means that it is in ASCII format:

```
$ cat p3.ppm
P3 4 4 255
  0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0   255  0 255
  0  0  0    0 255 127  0  0  0    0  0  0
  0  0  0    0  0  0    0 255 127  0  0  0
255  0 255   0  0  0    0  0  0    0  0  0
```

[image: view of sample PPM image]

If you prefer, you can write a "P6" formatted PPM file, in which
the pixels are raw bytes;

```
$ od -c p6.ppm
0000000   P   6  \n   4       4  \n   2   5   5  \n  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000020  \0  \0  \0  \0 377  \0 377  \0  \0  \0  \0 377 177  \0  \0  \0
0000040  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 377 177  \0  \0  \0 377
0000060  \0 377  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll go with this until I find a lib for PNG's :-)

Comment: I assume the downvote was because I didn't specifically say how to do it with swift.  The format is so simple that if you can write a "hello world" program you can write a p3.ppm.  I write them with Fortran, vi, echo, bash "here documents", etc.  I wrote the example here with the StackExchange markdown editor, and then converted it to P6 with GraphicsMagick.